# Terminal - RVM Error

Tags: ruby, bash, installation, rvm

I am receiving an error message after attempting to install RVM and I need help figuring out why I'm getting this message and how to fix it. When I open up a terminal window, this is the message I receive:

```
 -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I do have a bash folder in the home directory, however I don't see /etc/profile. I've since uninstalled RVM but this error message still shows, I'm currently running Ruby 1.8.7.

After running `rvm implode` I received the following message:

```
Note you may need to manually remove /etc/rvmrc and ~/.rvmrc if they exist still.
Please check all .bashrc .bash_profile .profile and .zshrc for RVM source lines and delete           
or comment out if this was a Per-User installation.
Also make sure to remove `rvm` group if this was a system installation.
Finally it might help to relogin / restart if you want to have fresh environment
```

If anyone has any ideas or insight on this I'd be happy to hear your thoughts, I'm kind of at a standstill so any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Comment: You should show what command you used to install RVM. I am guessing you didn't read the *entire* [RVM installation instructions](http://RVM.io/rvm/install), and tried to use `sudo` in some way. `/etc/profile` is not in your home directory, it's a system-owned file for all users.

Comment: @TinMan Yes I did use sudo at some point, I read the installation instructions however now I'm wondering if I accidentally installed multi-user instead of single. I just ran a search for /etc/profile and several function files popped up, this is what I found:        install_template "riak/riak.sh" \
      to "/etc/profile.d/${package_name}.sh" \
      mode 0755

Comment: You NEVER need to use `sudo` with RVM for a single user install, it's only for the multi-user install. The installation directions are clear about that. The RVM authors are very responsive and can help you unwind the problem. Does the problem persist when you open a new terminal window?

Comment: Oh okay..Yes this message appears in every terminal window. I'll reach out to the RVM authors thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing rvm from your terminal

```
$ rm /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

$ rm ~/.rvmrc
```

and then check your bash profile

```
$ open bash_profile

$ open .bashrc
```

Delete any line that has rvm.